# Show the total of a column for each group in its own row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**My select statement returns:**

```
columnA ColumnB ColumnC DATE
"this"   5        3     
"this"   5        3      
"this"   5        3      
"that"   10       5     
"that"   10       5      
"that"   10       5
```

**I need my select to return this:**

```
columnA ColumnB ColumnC DATE
"this"   5        3
"this"   5        3
"this"   5        3
Total    15       9
"that"   10       5
"that"   10       5
"that"   10       5
Total    30       15
```

I need to group by column A and show a total for each group in its own row. Date is populated in my code.

All I can think of is selecting all column A possibilities, then looping through the columnA names, selecting all with that column name, then unioning each of these to each other. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can simply write an aggregate query and do a UNION with your SELECT statement, but it depends on what you want in you DATE column.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with `grouping sets`.  However, you don't have unique identifiers for each row.  So, I think this is the logic:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from (<your query here>) t
     )
select columnA, sum(columnB), sum(ColumnC)
from t
group by grouping sets((seqnum, columnA), (columnA));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, It will give result as per your requirement

```
select columnA,columnB,columnC   from  tablename
union all
select columnA,sum(columnB),SUM(columnC)  
from tablename group by col1 
order by columnA,columnB,columnC
```